# Reflection - cannot copy propertyValue

Tags: c#, reflection

One would think that this should be trivial. However, I must be doing something wrong and I have been unable to understand what.

As part of a WebAPI2 project, I have a simple interface IDefaultView

```
public class IDefaultView
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        //....other properties
    }
```

and a class View that implements this interface.

```
public class View : IDefaultView
    {
        public string Description  { get; set; }

        public View(MyObject obj)
        {
            Id = obj.Id;
            //....other properties
            Description = obj.Description;
        }
    }
```

The View Class is actually a DTO that is consumed by an API Controller.

I am currently experimenting various solutions to perform API Controller unit testing, among which is the creation of a `BaseTestClass`. Simplified outline of the BaseTestClass is shown below.

```
public class BaseTestClass<entityViewClass> where entityViewClass : IDefaultView
    {
        public void Method1 ()
        {
            //...stripped out code
            //controller below is a reference to the controller, whose addNew(item) method results in a CreatedAtRouteNegotiatedContentResult<View> object.
            var result = controller.addNew(item) as CreatedAtRouteNegotiatedContentResult<entityViewClass>;
            string newDescription = GetPropertyValue(result.Content, "Description").ToString ();
            //...stripped out code
        }
        public object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName)
        {
            var objType = obj.GetType();
            var prop = objType.GetProperty(propertyName);
            return prop.GetValue(obj, null);
        }
    }
```

I am getting a behaviour that I cannot understand when using reflection to access the `Description` property as it never gets assigned to the `newDescription` variable.

I have added a break point and a watch on `GetPropertyValue(result.Content, "Description").ToString ()` and it shows the correct property value. However, the `newDescription` variable never gets set. The watch windows even shows: The name 'newDescription' does not exist in the current context.

I initially thought that this was related to the fact that the interface definition does not include the `Description` property, but `Description` property is accessible as confirmed by the watch.

What am I missing? I would appreciate if anybody out there came across the same issue or has any idea about what is going on.

Thanks !

Comment: This is not a well written question in my opinion. See "Sample code and data" http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: Edited to provide more context information.